# Which version of Spring framework security is compatible with Spring framework 5.3.4

Tags: spring, spring-security, version, spring-framework-beans

Currently, I am using

```
<springFramework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</springFramework.version>
<springFrameworkSecurity.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</springFrameworkSecurity.version>
```

I want to move to

```
<springFramework.version>5.3.4.RELEASE</springFramework.version>
<springFrameworkSecurity.version> ? </springFrameworkSecurity.version>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.x/reference/html5/#getting) for the latest Spring Security:

> Since Spring Security makes breaking changes only in major releases, it is safe to use a newer version of Spring Security with Spring Boot.

The Spring Framework version you're moving to is `5.3.4`, so I would assume that any `5.X.X` version of Spring Security *should* work.

If that works, let us know by [marking the answer as solved](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)! If not, leave a comment.